# Does the align environment provided by amsmath not enter math mode?

Tags: amsmath

I asked a question earlier today, where I learned that the `subequations` environment provided by amsmath does not enter math mode:  [Missing $ inserted error when using \frac inside subequations environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218882/missing-inserted-error-when-using-frac-inside-subequations-environment)

According to the [documentation](http://ctan.mirror.rafal.ca/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf) however, align should enter math mode (see pg. 10). Then, why does the following MNWE (minimum not working example) not work?

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\section{Hello World}
    \begin{subequations}
        \begin{align}
            \frac{a}{b} &= 0 \\

            x + y &= \frac{a}{b} \\
        \end{align}
    \end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

The errors being produced seemingly suggesting once again that align is not a math mode environment?

```
line 14: Missing $ inserted I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
line 15: Missing \endgroup inserted x + y &
line 15: Missing $ inserted x + y &= \frac{a}{b}
line 15: Extra }, or forgotten $ x + y &= \frac{a}{b}
line 16: Misplaced \cr \end{align}
line 16: Missing $ inserted \end{align}
line 16: Missing } inserted \end{align}
line 16: Misplaced \noalign \end{align}
line 16: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup \end{align}
line 16: Missing $ inserted \end{align}
line 0: Display math should end with $$
```

In particular, note the error for line 14: "I think therefore I insert $?". Okay, all jokes aside, what's up here? Am I not understanding the documentation correctly?

Comment: Don't leave a blank line inside `align`...

Comment: In addition to what Werner suggests, remove the \\ from the final row of the `align`, or else you get a blank line labeled `(1c)`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Ah! So it's not the `\\` marks that define a "new equation line"?

Comment: `align` does not like empty lines inside of it. Removing all empty lines makes everything work okay. Thanks to [Werner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5764/werner) for pointing this out in the comments above.

Comment: Yes, \\ for sure finishes the current line.  In environments like `tabular`, placing it on the last line is ignored.  But in `align` type environments, placing \\ on the final line actually creates a blank following line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is even more than in your answer (now comment). In any form of math mode, `\par` and equivalent forms, like an empty line, causes an error. The reason is in the Chapter 16, p. 135 of *The TeXbook*

> Conversely, a blank line or \par is not permitted in math mode. This gives
>   TeX another way to recover from a missing $; such errors will be confined to
>   the paragraph in which they occur.